# Duas funções no mesmo evento onclick javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas funções que precisam interagir na mesma `DIV`.

### # ambienteEdit(this);

A função dela é que **ao manter a DIV pressionada por 3 segundos**, seja aberto a tela de `confirm()` do javascript, passando o ID.

### # vistoriaIniciar(this);

Essa função, ao clicar apenas uma vez na DIV seja encaminhado para outra outra tela passando alguns parâmetros.

### Tentativa:

`<div class="lista fade" onclick="ambienteEdit(this);vistoriaIniciar(this)">`

`vistoriaIniciar()`, funciona, mas o `ambienteEdit()` não funciona. Se eu removo o `vistoriaIniciar()` a função `ambienteEdit()` funciona.

### Pergunta:

Como fazer para ter os dois eventos na mesma `DIV`?

Obrigado.

```js
function ambienteEdit(object) {
   let aID     = object.getElementsByClassName('aID')[0].value;

   let delay;
   document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
     delay = setTimeout(_ => confirm("Dialogo"), 3000)
   });

   document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
     clearTimeout(delay);
   });

   console.log(aID)
}



function vistoriaIniciar(object) {
  let aID     = object.getElementsByClassName('aID')[0].value;
  let aCodigo = object.getElementsByClassName('aCodigo')[0].value;
  let aNome   = object.getElementsByClassName('aNome')[0].value;

  window.location='vistoriaIniciar.html?codigo='+aCodigo+'&ambiente='+aNome+'&id_ambiente='+aID;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista fade" onclick="ambienteEdit(this);vistoriaIniciar(this)">
  BLA BLA BLA
</div>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro no CONSOLE?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Sem erro, só não executa o `ambienteEdit`.

Comment: Porque você quer que o sistema aguarde 3 segundos para abrir uma confirmação?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751982/11890088

Comment: @DanielZazula porque é algo que estou fazendo para celular. Na mesma DIV a pessoa passa para outra tela, mas se a pessoa manter pressionado abrirá a tela de edição.

Comment: Adicionar deliberadamente a todo click um document.addEventListener está errado, tanto na sua pergunta quanto nas respostas, não é assim que se usa os eventos ouvintes, pode até funcionar, mas não está correto e vai registrando uma série de coisas que não estarão mais sendo usadas, consumindo o que não faz nada após a primeira adição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O evento `onclick` só vai ser disparado se você clicar e soltar. Com isso, o `document.addEventListener("mousedown"...` só será criado se isso acontecer ao menos uma vez.

Chame a função `ambienteEdit` num atributo de evento `onmousedown` na div:

```
<div class="lista fade" onclick="vistoriaIniciar(this)" onmousedown="ambienteEdit(this)">
```

E a função ficará assim:

```
function ambienteEdit(object) {
   let aID     = object.getElementsByClassName('aID')[0].value;

   let delay = setTimeout(_ => confirm("Dialogo"), 3000)

   document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
     clearTimeout(delay);
   });

   console.log(aID)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo um redirect no método  `vistoriaIniciar()`

```
window.location='vistoriaIniciar.html?codigo='+aCodigo+'&ambiente='+aNome+'&id_ambiente='+aID;
```

E está esperando  3 segundos para rodar o confirm no método `ambienteEdit()`

O que acontece é que o redirect está acontecendo antes de 3 segundos, por isso parece que seu método não foi chamado, mas ele simplesmente está esperando os 3 segundos.

Por isso que ele funciona quando você tira `vistoriaIniciar()`, porque não tem redirect.

Para resolver faça o seguinte, mova o seu método `ambienteEdit` para o LOAD da pagina e remova ele do onclick da div, vai ficar assim.

```
<script>

    window.onload = function load() {
         var div =  document.getElementById("onPressDiv");
        ambienteEdit(div);
    }

function ambienteEdit(object) {
   let aID     = object.getElementsByClassName('aID')[0].value;

   let delay;
   document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
     delay = setTimeout(_ => confirm("Dialogo"), 3000)
   });

   document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
     clearTimeout(delay);
   });

   console.log(aID)
}



function vistoriaIniciar(object) {
  let aID     = object.getElementsByClassName('aID')[0].value;
  let aCodigo = object.getElementsByClassName('aCodigo')[0].value;
  let aNome   = object.getElementsByClassName('aNome')[0].value;

  window.location='vistoriaIniciar.html?codigo='+aCodigo+'&ambiente='+aNome+'&id_ambiente='+aID;
}
   </script>
```

E sua div.

```
<div class="lista fade" id="onPressDiv" onclick="vistoriaIniciar(this)">
            BLA BLA BLA
        </div>
```

Comment: Qual seria a solução?

Comment: @Thiago Eu não sei o que você quer fazer, eu separaria os métodos, REDIRECT em um elemento e abrir o confirm em outro

Comment: Se clicar uma vez na DIV, vai para outra tela. Se clicar e segurar por 3 segundos, abre o confirm.

Comment: @Thiago tenta desse modo.